# How does CS-Cart handle the storefront index page on the back-end side?

Tags: php, cs-cart

I am trying to add custom sections to the homepage in between product rows, which include products filtered with custom queries not provided by default from CS-Cart.
The usual way of doing this via code (the project is customized to the point that CMS functionality in this case doesn't help) is to do some logic in the proper controller and assign the data to the view.

By researching I know that the index page is handled differently from the other pages meaning that it doesn't follow the controller->view pattern.

How is the index view (homepage) handled on the back-end? Where is the logic for the index page and how do I edit it to customize my homepage?

Answer (score 0):

On backend > homepage CS-Cart follow the same pattern and the files are:

## php

```
app/controllers/backend/index.php
```

To add your own php code you can add it by adding into file

```
app/addons/[ADDON_NAME]/controllers/backend/index.post.php
```

## tpl

```
design/backend/templates/views/index/index.tpl
```

Please check tpl file because there are already available some hooks

Comment: Hello, and thank you for the answer. My question was about the storefront index page. Editing the question as I can see how it may be misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

you have to edit config.local file with this code

```
$config['customer_index'] = '<Your_new_index_path>';
```